# How can I hide titles with render()?

Tags: theming

I'm using the Devel module, and the following snippet of code to insert its links into my theme.

```
<?php echo render($page['devel']); ?>
```

The result is a h2 element with the **Development** title in it, and then followed by the links as expected.

I want to hide the title, is it possible at all?

---

This is what I ended up doing.

```
<ul id="devel-menu">
    <?php if(array_key_exists('menu_devel', $page['devel'])):?>
        <?php foreach($page['devel']['menu_devel'] as $link):?>
            <?php if(is_array($link) && array_key_exists('#title', $link)):?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $link['#href'];?>"><?php echo $link['#title'];?></a></li>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endif;?>
</ul>
```

Does this seem acceptable, or is there a preferred way to do this in Drupal?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the render array itself, but try `$page['devel']['#title_display'] = 'invisible';` before rendering

Comment: Thanks Clive, I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work at all, I looked through the array for $page['devel'], but theres not an obvious way to hid the title.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing, and it works 100%:

```
<ul id="devel-menu">
    <?php if(array_key_exists('menu_devel', $page['devel'])):?>
        <?php foreach($page['devel']['menu_devel'] as $link):?>
            <?php if(is_array($link) && array_key_exists('#title', $link)):?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $link['#href'];?>"><?php echo $link['#title'];?></a></li>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endif;?>
</ul>
```